# Scroll image at center and zoom at the center

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

A set of images are vertically aligned at the center of the page.
On keyPress I am able to zoom that image.

For example: If I try to zoom the image which is out of the page, It is zoomed somewhere out of the page or the image is cropped.

All I want to do is, when I keyPress, i wan to make to changes

1. Make the zoomed image at center of the page.
2. I want an image to zoom **only after** the previous image is zoomed back to its position.

My code is http://fiddle.jshell.net/PB49p/

Comment: this you can tell ysterday only  rt :) ?

Comment: I thought the question would be too long and none would answer or just downvote. So i just limited my question to transition yesterday :)

Comment: Also I have one more question related to this, which I will ask after this :)

Comment: So can I get any luck on this question?

Comment: :D .. so this requirement is vague .. you just want the zoomed image always at the center . is that all ?

Comment: Yes, image selected should also be at the center, moving other images upwards.

Comment: why didn't you try any Jquery image Carousel plugins ?

Comment: I want to do this JavaScript not JQuery

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42922/discussion-between-sarath-and-archana)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to move the wrapper to adjust the position

```
function scrollWrapper(n) {
  var tansvalue  = -150 * (n-1);
  wrapper.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:translate(0,'+tansvalue+'px);');
}
```

and dely you can adjust with [`-webkit-transition-delay:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay)

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/PB49p/2/)

Comment: Thankyou @Sarath. With your help I was able to achieve what I want. Here is a [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6H34m/), that shows scrolling and centering the images and delayed and smooth transition.